# Different Redirection Results

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, redirection, browser-cache

When my brother uses any of his browsers to try to go to olbert.com, or www.olbert.com, he gets redirected to a non-existent site (which was a valid site I used to operate). This occurs in both Firefox and Chrome, on his machine.

When I try to go to either site, I end up at a valid site (the master blog page for a set of WordPress blogs I run). This is true in both Chrome and Firefox.

I'm confused as to why the same URL would take two different computers to two different locations. FYI, we've both cleared our browser caches, with the same results.

Comment: Are you both on the same network? Are the DNS servers the same? Have you looked in his hosts file? Does nslookup give a different IP address on each machine?

Comment: Different networks. Thanx for the other suggestions, I’ll check them out.